# Problem add site to IIS6

Tags: iis-6, windows-xp

I have installed IIS6 in my pc that have the OS in XP.
I have installed 
- IIS6 Manager,
- IIS6 Resource Kit Tools

I can open:
 Start>Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Internet Information Services (IIS6) Manager ,

But I cant add new site in IIS, I can't see the wwwroots site.
In the right click in Internet Information Services I can do only connect to one other pc.

Any ideas???

Thnax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have installed IIS6 in my pc that have the OS in XP.

I doubt it. IIS6 is part of Windows Server 2003. It doesn't run on vanilla XP, which uses IIS5.1.

> I have installed - IIS6 Manager, - IIS6 Resource Kit Tools

That's not IIS6, that's only an interface to configure IIS6 installations on this or other machines. It is of no use to you. If you want to install IIS on an XP machine, as previously mentioned in your other question, you must have a copy of the XP Pro install CD.

> But I cant add new site in IIS

You won't be able to add a new site even in a working IIS on XP. As XP is not a server OS, you will be limited to running a single web site, the ‘Default Web Site’ IIS comes configured with.

(There are script hacks you can run to add more sites if you must, but you can only actually serve one site at once.)

Answer (score 2):

The Resource Kit Tools only include the manager that allows you to connect to OTHER computers running IIS. You will need to install IIS directly on the machine (it needs to be XP Pro as well - not home edition). See this link - it is fairly straighforward add/remove windows components.
http://www.learnthat.com/courses/computer/windowsxp/iis/